# Using case when to insert values

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, timezone, extract

Below shows a executable statement:
Successful attempt:

```
INSERT INTO Personnel_Assignment (DATE, testno, Hours) 
SELECT '21-OCT-2011', '12345', 
   CASE
      WHEN Extract(day From(S.ENDTIME-S.STARTTIME) ) >= 1 
         THEN (Extract(Day From(S.ENDTIME-S.STARTTIME) ) * 24 
            + Extract(Hour From(S.ENDTIME-S.STARTTIME) ) )
      WHEN S.endtime IS NULL
         THEN NULL
      ELSE
         Extract(Hour From(S.ENDTIME-S.STARTTIME) ) )
      ||'hrs' End ||
      Extract(Minute From(S.ENDTIME-S.STARTTIME) ) || 'Min' As Hours 
FROM Schedule S`
```

Please note that the data type for endtime and start time is timestamp with timezone in this format:

```
Nls_Timestamp_Tz_Format='HH24:MI TZR'
```

Just a question that i would like to ask:
My datatype for hours is varchar2
And if i wish to sum my hours in the end from the results above, would it be tedious in converting it into number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `|| Else` doesn't make sense. The part after `||` has to be another expression to concatenate.

Secondly, you certainly *can* nest `case` expressions, but in your case you don't need to. A single `case` expression can have multiple `when`/`then` branches, in the form `case when [condition_A] then [expression_if_A_is_true] when [condition_B] then [expression_if_A_is_false_and_B_is_true] else [expression_if_A_and_B_are_both_false] end`.

Comment: Ok i understood your second solution. But i don't understand your first solution given. Do you mean that i cannot put > || before else?

Comment: @user976050: You can't, because it doesn't make any sense. `||` comes between two expressions and concatenates their values into a single string; for example, `'a' || 'b'` is equivalent to `'ab'`. But an `else ...` clause isn't an expression. What is `||` supposed to concatenate in that case?

Comment: By the way, `then ||` also doesn't make sense, for the same reason.

Comment: Oh ok. I have followed your method and make the changes but i have a missing keyword error. Is it due to my 'then null' ? i want it to be inserted null if s.endtime is null

Comment: @user976050: `then null` is fine. Why don't you edit your question, adding something like "**UPDATE:** My query now looks like this: ..."? Otherwise I (and others) would just have to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: But i have a missing keyword error after changing my when, then. It leads to me WHEN s.endtime is null Then null Else. May I know did i wrote something wrong ? I'll change my problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: You now have `|| end`, which is the same sort of problem as `|| else` and `then ||`. I'm guessing you mean `end ||`; that is, you want to take the result of the `case ... end` expression and concatenate it to what follows.

Comment: Ok. I think this would be the last issue. When i express the string in the end, ||'hours||. It overwrite the null values to hoursmin. How can i do to remain the null value ?

Comment: @user976050: You moved too much! You need to change `End ||'hrs'||` to `||'hrs' End ||` -- that is, you need the `|| 'hrs'` to be *inside* the `case ... end` expression, and the second `||` to be *outside* the `case ... end` expression. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi i always thought that ||'hrs'|| should be after end. But thanks. Just a simple question, if i want to sum the values of hours and minutes in the end. AND the hours data type i'm using is varchar2. Is it very complex to convert it to number and sum it up? Thanks