# SQL - is it possible to have an if inside the values of an insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a script to insert data selected from one table into another.  The old table stores a value 'Yes' in one column but I want to insert 1 instead of 'Yes'

Is there any way to do this.  In my head this is what I want to do:

```
insert into new_table (new_col1, new_col2)
values (select from old_table(old_col1, (if old_col2='Yes' then 1 else 0))
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8176902/447514

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: if you base your insert on a SELECT, the must not use the `VALUES` clause.

To get a conditional value, use the (ANSI standard) CASE statement:

```
insert into new_table (new_col1, new_col2)
select old_col1, 
       case 
         when old_col2 = 'Yes' then 1 
         else 0 
       end
from old_table
```

An Oracle only more compact form would be the decode() statement (but I'd recommend to use the CASE, because it's more readable and portable to other DBMS as well)

```
insert into new_table (new_col1, new_col2)
select old_col1, 
       decode(old_col2, 'Yes', 1, 0)
from old_table
```

Comment: One other question, is the Yes case sensitive?  If I want to check for YES, Yes and yes would it still work or do I need to do something else.

Comment: @Kaskade: Yes, character comparison in Oracle is case sensitive by default. But you can use `when lower(old_col2) = 'yes'` to make the test case-insensitive.

Comment: brilliant thanks - sorry for such a basic question.  I am not a sql developer.  I was given a task to copy some data but turns out it wasn't that simple.  Nearly there now though!

Comment: +1 for the inclusion of DECODE with the explaination of why CASE is the preferred option.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [`CASE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) statement.

```
CASE
WHEN old_col2='Yes' then 1 
ELSE 0
END
```